# Gradle build type "debug" does not merge mipmap images?

Tags: android-gradle-plugin

In my build.gradle, I have three build types:

```
buildTypes {
    debug {
        applicationIdSuffix ".debug"
        debuggable true
    }
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
    }
    beta {
        applicationIdSuffix ".beta"
        debuggable true
    }
}
```

For all three build types, I have different icons in mipmap-xxx directories. The idea is, if I install all the three apks on the same device, I can easily identify each app.

When I run gradle to build the apks, I see that the icon files in the intermediate directory for beta have been merged properly. However, the ones for debug `build\intermediates\res\merged\debug\mipmap-xxx`still use the original images for "release."

I am wondering if "debug" build type is special and if there is a way to tell gradle to merge the icons. Regards.

Note that the string table does get merged properly for all the build types.

Comment: In which folder  did you put the images?

Comment: After your comment, I carefully studies the directory structure. Turns out my mipmap-xxx dir was one directory up. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It turns out I made a mistake in the directory layout. The proper layout must be as follows:

```
src/
  main/
    java/
    res/
      values/
      mipmap-xxx/
  beta/
    res/
      values/
      mipmap-xxx/
  debug/
    res/
      values/
      mipmap-xxx/
```

Comment: This helped me realise I named my folder differently than my buildType. -.- . Thanks